# generate random RGB color using rand() function

Tags: c, random, colors, svg, srand

I need a function which will generate three numbers so I can use them as RGB pattern for my SVG.
While this is simple, I also need to make sure I'm not using the same color twice.
How exactly do I do that? Generate one number at a time with simple `rand` (seed time active) and then what? I don't want to exclude a number, but maybe the whole pattern?
I'm kind of lost here.

To be precise, by first calling of this function I will get for example 218 199 154 and by second I'll get 47 212 236 which definitely are two different colors. Any suggestions?

Also I think a `struct` with `int r, int g, int b` would be suitable for this?

**Edit:** Colors should be different to the human eye. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier.

Comment: In order to guarantee that the same color is never used twice just store colors generated so far in a linked list(or hash map if you have access to one). Keep on applying rand until your number is not in that set.

Comment: Another consideration: is it "same color" for computer or for a person? If second, then a single unit of difference in one of RGB numbers is probably not enough to make it different enough to the eye.

Comment: @Arkadiy: yes different to the human eye. Not just a different hue of the same color which won't be recognizable.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: is random working with the probability law? I mean do I have 1/255 to generate a number? meaning in 1 out of 255 I would get for example 1 .. What is the probability I won't get 255 255 0 and 255 255 1? There would be a case when this will happen is that right or am I completely wrong?

Comment: in that case you need a comparison procedure that decides = / != based on human perception...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a set to store the generated colors.
First instanciate a new set.
Then, every time you generate a color, look if the value is present in your set. 
If the record exists, skip it and retry for a new colour. If not, you can use it but dont forget to cache it in the Set after.
This may become not performant if you need to generate a big quantity of colour.

Comment: This seems like a good solution, but how do I ensure it would generate two different colors for two different calls, while those colors would be different to human eye not just to computer, what I mean it will be yellow and purple not yellow and light yellow (which human eye will hardly recognize).

Comment: Ok then after generating a color you have to scan the generated color list to check that it's not too close. You have to  decide a minimum scoree between 2 colors (r,g,b) that would make the result unique. If all the three (r g and b) value are too close to an existing color you start a new generation.IE r: 200 g :200 b : 200 . if you generate 199;199;150 with a scoree set to 5 it's fine thanks to blue. If you gnerate 195,198,197 all the 3 colors interval are under the scoree limit.

Comment: all right, I did what you said, because this seems to be the easiest solution for me and it seems to be working just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest way to do this would be to use a [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) which is very small memory wise, but leads to occasional false positives (i.e., you will think you have used a colour, but you haven't). Basically, create three random numbers between 0-255, save them however you like, hash them as a triplet and place the hash in the filter.

Also, you might want to throw away the low bits of each channel since it's probably not easy to tell #FFFFF0 versus #FFFFF2.

Comment: This is interesting, but the problem is a bit more complex as I want to assure both same colors won't happen again and 255 255 0 for first call and 255 255 1 for the second won't happen as well. (since this is hardly recognizable)

Comment: I am aware of that. My suggestion doesn't produce them in that order. I just mean that when computing the hashing functions in the filter, you should throw away the low bits to prevent that kind of duplication.

Comment: I've managed to achieve that with different solution, but thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way:

```
1.Generate a random integer.
2.Shift it 8 times to have 24 meaningful bits, store this integer value.
3.Use first 8 bits for R, second group of 8 bits for G,
      and the remaining 8 bits for B value.
```

For every new random number, shift it 8 times, compare all the other integer values that you stored before, if none of them matches with the new one use it for  the new color(step3).

The differentiation by human eye is an interesting topic, because perceptional thresholds vary from one to another person. To achieve it shift the integer 14 times, get the first 6 bits for R(pad two 0s to get 8 bits again), get the second 6 bits for G, and last 6 bits for B. If you think that 6 bits are not good for it, decrease it 5,4...

Simple Run with 4 significant bits for each channel:
My random integer is:

```
0101-1111-0000-1111-0000-1100-1101-0000
```

I shift(you can also use multiply or modulo) it to left 20 times:

```
0000-0000-0000-0000-0000-0101-1111-0000
```

store this value.

Then get first 4 bits for R second 4 bits for G and last 4 bits for B:

```
R: 0101
G: 1111
B: 0000
```

Pad them to make each of them 8 bits.

```
R: 0101-0000
G: 1111-0000
B: 0000-0000
```

Use those for your color components.

For each new random number after shifting it compare it with your stored integer values so far. If it is different, then store and use it for color.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use a bit vector to represent the set of colors generated. For 24-bit precision, the bit vector would be 2<sup>24</sup> bits long, which is 16,777,216 bits, or 2 MB. Certainly not a lot, these days, and it would be very fast to look up and insert colors.

Comment: could you explain a little more? :)